# Semisimplicity for tensor products of representations of finite groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, tensor-products

Let $G$ be a group and $k$ a field of characteristic $p>0$. Let $$\rho_i: G\to GL(V_i),~ i=1,2$$ be two finite-dimensional semisimple $k$-representations of $G$, with $\dim(V_1)+\dim(V_2)<p+2.$  Then [a 1994 theorem of Serre](https://eudml.org/doc/144198) tells us that $\rho_1\otimes\rho_2$ is semisimple.

> **I was wondering -- is there is an easier proof in the case that $G$ is *finite*?**

Specializing Serre's proof to the case of finite groups seems not to yield any real simplification; one has to apply the so-called *saturation* technique to replace the subgroup of $G$ generated by elements of order a power of $p$ by a linear-algebraic group.

I suspect the answer is "no" -- it seems to me that the general case reduces to the case of finite groups (by a spreading out and specialization argument), so it's hard to believe this case could be substantially easier -- but I figured it was worth asking. I'd also be interested in a proof with worse bounds, e.g. with $p+2$ replaced by any increasing function of $p$.

Comment: I don't think this is obvious in the finite case, and I don't think that the finite case was known in that generality before Serre's proof appeared. If a simpler proof were found for the finite case, I am sure there would be significant interest in it.

Comment: That's my instinct as well -- as I remark in the question, I don't think it's too hard to reduce the general case to the case of finite groups, so by the principle of "conservation of work," the case of finite groups should be hard. Still, it's a bit surprising to me that such an innocent statement should be so difficult.

Comment: @DanielLitt "Still, it's a bit surprising to me that such an innocent statement should be so difficult." - Possibly a definition for groups.

Comment: I'm not a specialist in modular representation theory, and, probably because of that, there is no statement about modular representation theory (other than the ones that are exactly as in complex representation theory) that seems innocent to me.

Comment: @LSpice: to be fair the analogous statement to Serre’s result in characteristic zero (that tensor products of semisimple representations of *arbitrary* groups are semisimple) is non-trivial, and relies on the theory of algebraic groups (it’s due to Chevalley). This claim about finite groups in characteristic p implies that result about arbitrary groups, though!

Comment: What makes tensor product special? Where does this fail for arbitrary representation?

Comment: @VítTuček: If you take $G=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ then the $2$-dimensional $\mathbb{F}_p$-representation sending $x$ to the upper triangular matrix with $1$'s on the diagonal and $x$ in the upper-right-hand corner is not semisimple.

Answer (score 2):

There is a result of D. S. Passmann and D. Quinn in "Burnside's theorem for Hopf algebras", Corollary 8, which says the following:

> If $A$ is a finite-dimensional Hopf algebra, then the set of semisimple
>   $A$-modules is closed under tensor product if and only if the Jacobson
>   radical $J(A)$ is a Hopf ideal of $A$.

If you require all semisimple $A$-modules to be closed under tensor products, then the question reduces to something about the Jacobson radical.

In a paper of M. Lorenz, "Representations of Finite-Dimensional Hopf Algebras", he makes the following comments:

> Remarks and Examples. 1) If  all  simple $H$-modules are 
>   1-dimensional (equivalently, $H/J\simeq k^r$ as $k$-algebras  for  some $r$), then  all 
>   tensor  products  of simple $H$-modules are  1-dimensional as  well, and
>   hence  condition (2) of the lemma is clearly satisfied. Thus $J$ is a
>   Hopf ideal in this case. ......
>
> 2) If $H=kG$ is a finite group algebra, then $J$ is a
>   Hopf ideal precisely if $G$ has a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup  [M].

[M] R. K. Molner, "Tensor products and  semisimple modular representations  of finite groups  and  restricted  Lie  algebras", Rocky  Mountain J.  Math. 111981 ,  581-591.

Comment: This seems to address  a different question. Serre's result is about tensoring two low dimensional semisimple representations to get another semisimple representation. It doesn't require that all semisimple representations are closed under tensoring.

Comment: As I said in my post, "If you require all semisimple -modules to be closed under tensor products, then the question reduces to something about the Jacobson radical."  I was just thinking, if you have more, then certainly you would have less.